# Parsing Json in PHP

Tags: php, json, parsing

Given below is my json array which i got after doing a

```
$data = json_decode($response);

foreach($data[songs] as $key => $value) {
 echo $value['title']; 
}
```

i get an error saying this Illegal string offset 'songs'. Can anyone help ?

```
{
   "response":{
      "status":{
         "version":"4.2",
         "code":0,
         "message":"Success"
      },
      "start":0,
      "total":169,
      "songs":[
         {
            "id":"SOVZDWG13EDE8AA5F6",
            "title":"Live And Let Die (Professional Backing Track)"
         },
         {
            "id":"SOVZQDT1373E96845D",
            "title":"Cival War"
         },
         {
            "id":"SOIHVBA1373E967FC7",
            "title":"Free Fallin'"
         },
         {
            "id":"SOHTILC137377A4D5A",
            "title":"PARADISE CITY (1989 Radio Edit)\/(CONTENT!)"
         },
         {
            "id":"SOTHTHM137376FDC30",
            "title":"IT'S SO EASY (CC Cleaner Edit)\/(LYRICS!)\/(CONTENT!)"
         },
         {
            "id":"SOSGUMG137392B086C",
            "title":"MR. BROWNSTONE (CC Clean)"
         },
         {
            "id":"SOAIMVY13739563B7F",
            "title":"NOVEMBER RAIN (Long Edit)"
         },
         {
            "id":"SOHTFWB13732F1645D",
            "title":"MOVE TO THE CITY (Live)\/(CC Clean)\/(CONTENT!)"
         },
         {
            "id":"SOINGWZ137337DD251",
            "title":"CIVIL WAR (CONTENT!)"
         },
         {
            "id":"SOJMUVZ136F21B42BC",
            "title":"Neurobomb"
         },
         {
            "id":"SOXPBNG136749B5A8B",
            "title":"SWEET CHILD O' MINE (Edit\/Remix)"
         },
         {
            "id":"SOCQGYZ1366D7B44B0",
            "title":"MADAGASCAR (CC Clean Edit)"
         },
         {
            "id":"SOXHMOW1366D7B84F6",
            "title":"RIAD N' THE BEDOUINS (CC Clean)"
         },
         {
            "id":"SOFCXWC1366DBED3DA",
            "title":"Nighttrain (Live)"
         },
         {
            "id":"SORXNZT1366E397CEC",
            "title":"DUST N' BONES (CC Clean)"
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

Comment: Read more about arrays keys.

Comment: Incidental to your question, but `$data[songs]` should be `$data['songs']`. It works without the quotes, but only because an ancient version of PHP allowed that and they haven't dared remove the "feature" yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
foreach($data->response->songs as $song) {
    print_r($song);
}
```

You had two problems.  One that you didn't access the `response` property, and that you weren't treating the result from `json_decode()` as an object.

Comment: Why wont it work with echo ?

Comment: It does.  `echo $song->id`.

Answer (score 2):

A simple `json_decode($jsonstring)` will return a mixture of stdClass objects and arrays. String keys are object properties, JSON arrays are PHP arrays starting at index 0.

Use `json_decode($jsonstring, true)` to only get arrays with string keys.

Comment: +1 didn't know about that parameter :)

Comment: This should be the right answer since it shows you how to get associative arrays like you are expecting. :P

Answer (score 1):

Just do var_dump($data) and your mistake will be obvious.

Comment: -1, it's an object, not an associative array

Comment: $data = json_encode($response);

foreach($data['response']['songs'] as $key => $value) 
{
  echo $value['title']; 
}

Comment: "it's an object, not an associative array" - which also would have been shown by a var_dump.

Comment: @Danack, Of course it would have been, but your answer is wrong and you didn't even update it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but I guess you can't access the data['songs'] without going threw 'response' first